# What is the shortcut for inverting stems in Guitar Pro 7?

Tags: guitar-pro, engraving

I have figured out how to change notes, swapping voices, etc using shortcuts provided by Guitar Pro 7.  Does anybody know a shortcut for inverting stems?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a keyboard shortcut, but there is a button on the editing palette. On the bottom row of that palette, the buttons with eighth-note markings include tools for changing stem direction and beaming.

See also the bottom of page 45 of the [user manual](https://download-fr-1.guitar-pro.com/gp7/manual/GuitarPro7-user-guide.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for a speedy and useful answer and I will dive right in to see if I got it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut for that feature.
I submitted a feature request for that, but for now it is not going to happen. Don't hesitate to suggest it if you use that feature a lot. Clicking on the button is annoying :)